# Which is the fastest session mode in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Which is the fastest session mode in ASP.NET?

**Options:**

```
InProc
StateServer
SQLServer
All of the above
```

Comment: exam cert question?  What do you think "is the fastest session mode in ASP.NET?"???

Comment: All is the fastest :D

Answer (score 2):

InProc should be the fastest because runs in the same process and uses memory, no serialization / deserealization is necessary but has major disadvantages, for example, recycling of the app pool will wipe everything out of session, it doesn't scale well or as easily as the other state providers.